# Route not working even respective settings are applied with program.cs

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, routes

I have enable Route() with .net core mvc 7 but not working
**program.cs code**

```
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=home}/{action=sign-in}/{id?}");
```

below is code for home controller

```
   [Route("sign-in")]
```

When I launch application, it redirect to notfound page and when I click from there [move to dashboard] it launch the page /account/sign-in. Which is perfectly fine as application designed.

Application must launch with account/sign-in page

When I replaced action="sign-in" with the original action name (as below), then it works fine.

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=home}/{action=signin}/{id?}")
```

Comment: For reproducing your problem, it needs to share part of program class and the controller that is related to the question. You can add [Route("/")] to the action that you want to map to default page

Answer (score 0):

Your routing works as intended.

What I think you want is to set what the initial route is opened in your browser when you start the application in Visual Studio?

To set that you go inside your application's project into `Properties\launchSettings.json`

Inside that file you'll find the `profiles` section which looks something like this:

```json
"profiles": {
    "CustomerApi": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44301;http://localhost:4301"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  },
```

You can notice that this example has two profiles for launching my application inside the Visual Studio. One is when I want to launch the application as a standalone program (opens the console), and the other is when I want to launch it using `IISExpress` (appears in your system tray).

For both of those you can set the `launchUrl` property to what URL the starting of the application should send you to.

For me it's set to go to `/swagger`. You can edit your properties to

```json
"launchUrl": "account/sign-in"
```